# How to use in_array in php with an array as needle but return true when there is at least one value match

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my `in_array` code

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

if(in_array(array('p', 'c'), $array)){
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
```

it returns not found, but actually I want it to return `found`, because there is one value match `c` .

Comment: Just wrap your in_array in a cycle and check every value of $array. Also you can write simple function to do that and reuse it in multiple places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea can be realized by using `array_intersect` and `count` functions.
 If there's at least one matched item between two arrays - `count` will return the number of matched items (1 or more):

```
$needle = array('p', 'c');
$haystack = array('a', 'b', 'c');

echo (count(array_intersect($needle, $haystack))) ? "found" : "not found";
// will output: "found"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 2):

use `array_interset()`:-

```
$search = array('p', 'c');
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$result = !empty(array_intersect($search , $array ));

var_dump($result); // print result

//OR
if(count($result) >=1){echo 'found';}else{'not found';}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/599429

Reference:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 2):

Another approach by creating a user function

```
function found_in_array($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($needle as $array) {
        if(in_array($array, $haystack)){
            return "found";
        }
    }

    return "not found";
}

$haystack = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$needle = array('p', 'c');

echo found_in_array($needle, $haystack);
```