# PHP-PDO: Search

Tags: php, pdo

my results are being duplicated by the number of occurrences in the table `device_transactions`
[my results currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC520.png)
[the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zltnV.png)

- Status returns **Ready** when **device name** has no corresponding record in the table `device_transactions` or there exists a corresponding record in the table `device_transactions` with the field *returned_date <> null*
- Status returns **Borrowing** when device name exists a corresponding record in `device_transactions` table with field *return_date == null*

`Table devices`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Projector |
| 2 | Laptop 001 |
| 3 | Laptop 002 |
| 4 | Humidifier |
| 5 | laptop 03 |

Table `device_transactions`:

| id | device_id | start_transaction_plan | end_transaction_plan | returned_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-12-10 14:20:43 | 2021-12-12 07:00:00 | 2021-12-12 9:30:23 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-12-11 10:10:20 | 2021-12-15 15:30:00 | 2021-12-16 7:30:45 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-12-12 19:03:00 | 2021-12-21 08:00:00 | NULL |
| 4 | 4 | 2021-12-10 14:20:43 | 2021-12-12 07:00:00 | 2021-12-12 9:30:23 |
| 5 | 4 | 2021-12-11 10:10:20 | 2021-12-15 15:30:00 | NULL |
| 6 | 2 | 2021-12-12 19:03:00 | 2021-12-21 08:00:00 | 2021-12-16 7:30:45 |
| 7 | 2 | 2021-12-10 14:20:43 | 2021-12-12 07:00:00 | 2021-12-12 9:30:23 |
| 8 | 2 | 2021-12-11 10:10:20 | 2021-12-15 15:30:00 | 2021-12-16 7:30:45 |
| 9 | 2 | 2021-12-12 19:03:00 | 2021-12-21 08:00:00 | NULL |
| 10 | 1 | 2021-12-11 10:10:20 | 2021-12-15 15:30:00 | 2021-12-16 7:30:45 |

below is the source code I made

**device.php**

```
<?php
    function searchADVDevice()
    {
        require '../common/connectDB.php';
        $keyword = '';
        $status = '';
        if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
            $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
        }
        if(isset($_GET['status'])){
            $status = $_GET['status'];
        }
        $sqlSearchString = '';
        if ($status == '') {
            $sqlSearchString = "select
            IF((device_transactions.device_id IS NULL OR (device_transactions.returned_date IS NOT NULL AND device_transactions.device_id IS NOT NULL)),1,2) as status,
            devices.id, devices.name, device_transactions.returned_date, device_transactions.device_id FROM devices
            LEFT JOIN device_transactions ON devices.id = device_transactions.device_id
            where name like '%$keyword%'";
        }
         else if ($status == 1) {
            $sqlSearchString = "select 1 as status, devices.id, devices.name, device_transactions.returned_date, 
            device_transactions.device_id FROM devices 
            LEFT JOIN device_transactions ON devices.id = device_transactions.device_id where 
            (device_transactions.device_id IS NULL OR (device_transactions.returned_date IS NOT NULL AND device_transactions.device_id IS NOT NULL)) AND
            devices.name like '%$keyword%' ";
        } 
        else if ($status == 2) {
            $sqlSearchString = "select 2 as status, devices.id, devices.name, device_transactions.returned_date, 
            device_transactions.device_id FROM devices
            LEFT JOIN device_transactions ON devices.id = device_transactions.device_id where 
            device_transactions.device_id IS NOT NULL AND device_transactions.returned_date IS NULL AND
            devices.name like '%$keyword%' ";
        }
        $sqlDeviceSearch = $conn->prepare($sqlSearchString);
        $sqlDeviceSearch->execute();
        $resultSearch = $sqlDeviceSearch->fetchAll() ;
        return $resultSearch;
    }
?>
```

**device_search_advaned_controller.php**

```
<?php
    require '../model/device.php';
    $resultSearch = searchADVDevice();  
?>
```

**SearchDevice.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TÌm kiếm thiết bị</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../web/css/device/searchAdvancedDevice.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content container">
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <div class="search">
                <div class="search_keyword">
                    <label>Key word</label>
                    <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['keyword'])) echo $_GET['keyword'] ?>" name="keyword">
                </div>
                <div class="search_status">
                    <label>Status</label>
                    <select id="status" name="status">
                        <option value=''>All</option>
                        <option value="1" <?php if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 1) echo 'selected' ?> >Ready</option>
                        <option value="2"  <?php if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 2) echo 'selected' ?>>Borrowing</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" id="btn_search">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php require '../controller/device_search_advaned_controller.php'; ?>
        <div class="count_device">
            <p>Number of devices found: <?php echo count($resultSearch) ?></p>
            
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th id="th_no">No</th>
                <th id="th_name">Device name</th>
                <th id="th_status">Status</th>
                <th id="th_action">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php 
           
            foreach ($resultSearch as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($row['status']) && $row['status'] == 2 ) {
                            echo "Borrowing";
                        } else {
                            echo "Ready";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($row['status']) && $row['status'] == 1) {
                            $b='<button id="btn_borrow"><a href="device_borrow_view.php">Borrow</a></button>';
                                echo $b;
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One of the ways :  select **distinct** xxxxx from [tablename] where [conditions....]

Comment: from my understanding with your requirement, you only want to show or let the user borrow an item when someone is not using it, i.e, `returned_date` is not `NULL`. Like Ken Lee comment, just use `distinct` with the condition `returned_date not NULL`. All the `if` can be replace with one `distinct` query

Comment: @zimorok Can you give a specific example in my post? because I don't know how to use `distinct` yet, so I'm quite confused as to how :((

Comment: Please be warned that the given queres are widely open for SQL injection. Even if you use prepared statements, you should not use string concatenation to add user-supplied data

Answer (score 1):

use `distinct` function to get the `device_id` which having `returned_date` as `null`, meaning it is currently not available

```
select distinct device_transactions.device_id, devices.name from devices join device_transactions on devices.id = device_transactions.device_id where device_transactions.returned_date is null;
```

the query will return all the item that is currently being borrowed. You can then compare this value against the `devices` table either with `in_array`, `array_diff` or `array_intersect` to set the necessary status

you can check more in here about comparing values
[How to use in_array in php with an array as needle but return true when there is at least one value match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157182/how-to-use-in-array-in-php-with-an-array-as-needle-but-return-true-when-there-is)

test the query online here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00bf16/8